# Related models issue in django 1.8

Tags: python, django

I wanted to add the [model-report](https://django-model-report.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html) module to my own app. After installing it and adding the installation directory to my Path I tried running the example project, only to get this error:

```
from django.db.models.related import RelatedObject
ImportError: No module named related
```

I think this has something to do with changes on version 1.8 since this module is quite old, but I do not know how to fix it exactly.

Has anyone any idea on how to fix the related module issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you activated your virtual environment?

EDIT:

## django 1.8 +

change your Import statement to:

from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignObjectRel

And then replace all RelatedObject with ForeignObjectRel

Comment: I am not using one, but I dont think this is causing the error though.

Comment: I guess I know the reason..The django.db.models.related module has been removed and the Field.related attribute will be removed in Django 2.0.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#model-field-related

Comment: Yeah i guessed it had something to do with the newer verisions of Django.

Comment: This does indeed fix it.

Comment: I am glad it helped, happy developing!